# Angular 8 (or 9) - get template html before its compiled

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create a "help site" for fellow developers at my company - showing them how to use components, etc.

What I'd like to do is create a component like the following that would show both the output and the code used to create the output:

```
<app-example>
  Hello World
  <app-icon name="test"></app-icon>
</app-example>
```

With the final source in the browser looking like the following:

```
<app-example>
  Hello World
  <app-icon _ngcontent-bfy-c15 ng-reflect-name="test"><svg ...></svg></app-icon>

  <code>
    Hello World
    &lt;app-icon name="test"&gt;&lt;/app-icon&gt;
  <code>
</app-example>
```

Unfortunately so far the best I can do is enter the code twice, once as html and once as a string:

```
<app-example>
  Hello World
  <app-icon name="test"></app-icon>
</app-example>

<app-code code='Hello World
&lt;app-icon name="test"&gt;&lt;/app-icon&gt;'></app-code>
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want? I'm open to using the JIT compiler if needed as this will only be an internal app.

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing can be done by [writing your own structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive). A structural directive allows to add, remove, or manipulate DOM elements.

i.e. you could write a `*codeSample` directive. When placed on an template element `<app-example>`, it would insert in the view both the `<app-example>` element as well as an extra `<app-code>` element.